# CNTLM doesn't work with cURL

Tags: ubuntu, curl, proxy, ntlm

In my virtual server I use CNTLM local proxy for accessing NTLM authentication. When I execute this command:

```
sudo curl -X GET "http://google.com"
```

It's work fine, but when I specify port, like this:

```
sudo curl -X GET "http://google.com:443"
```

I got error - %bla-bla-bla% Network is unreachable %bla-bla-bla%.
Maybe I wrong configured /etc/cntlm.conf? Please, help me.

P.S.
I use Ubuntu 14.04 under VirtualBox(with Vagrant).

Answer (score 1):

You missed the "Secure" in the protocol:

http://google.com:443 does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for answer.